# PHP: return array?

Tags: php

I have index.php, and function.php.

In index.php i have included function.php

In index.php im calling `login("Bla","123");` which exists in function.php

In index.php I have a `if (!empty($err)){ foreach(..) echo $err ... }`

login() should return a array called $err, (with return $err; ) if there is any errors, and then it should echo it out in the foreach in index.php..

But somehow I can not get it to work. Can't you do it like this? Im not getting anything back.

I have in the login() :

```
$err = array();
    $err[] = "Something went wrong";
        return $err;
        exit();
```

What's wrong here? Or any other solution to do this?

Comment: Why `exit()` after `return`? Can you show us the whole `login` function?

Comment: What does the code look like in index.php that sets $err?

Comment: PS it would really help to provide code that we can actually use to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` return returns the *value* of `$err`. It does not make the variable `$err` globally available.

Try using:

```
$err = login('Bla', '123');
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the `exit()` with **just** `return;`

```
function login()
{
    //Blah
    exit();
}
login();

echo 'You shall never see this.';
```

this is what you should be doing:

```
$errors = array();
function login($user,$pass)
{
    global $errors;
    if(empty($user) || empty($pass))
    {
        $errors[] = "username / Password invalid";
    }

    //More Checks

    //at the end.
    if(count($errors) == 0) /*no errors*/
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then in your `index.php`

```
if(!login("user","pass"))
{
    foreach($errors as $error)
    {
        echo $error . "<br />";
    }
    exit();
}

//Successful login
```

Comment: I've created a similar answer before, but then I realized that `exit()` never gets executed because Karem has used the `return` keyword (which terminates the function). I think Hamish is right.

Comment: yea, i meant replace exit with just `return;`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading up on variable scope:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Based on what you've said you're attempting to return a variable from one scope and use it in another scope using the same name, but without setting it explicitly.

```
function login() {
    $var = 123;
    return $var;
}

login(); // $var won't exist.
$abc = login(); // To login() it is called $var
// but here $abc has the same value as $var inside of login() because it was returned.
// not because it has the same name.
```

Answer (score 0):

ive already added one answer but i think ill add another describing OOP way to do this.

Create a file called `login.class.php` and create a class like so

```
class Login
{
    var $username,$password;

    public function __cosntruct($username,$password)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    //Checks
    public function isValidUsername()
    {
       return strlen($this->username) > 8;
    }

    //..Etc
}
```

then you can do:

```
$Login = new Login("Username","Password");

if(!$Login->isValidUsername())
{
    echo 'username invalid';
}
```